# Django count satisfied filters in queryset

Tags: python, django

Good day everyone.

I am trying to learn python and django for a few days now and have come across a challenge.

I would like to search a model, count the filters that was satisfied (like a score), then order them by that score in descending order.

I tried the following:

```
filter_count = 3
q1 = Q(fieldA__iexact='AAA')
q2 = Q(fieldB__iexact='BBB')
q3 = Q(fieldC__contains='CCC')
qAll = q1 | q2 | q3

results = myModel.objects.filter(qAll).annotate(
        match_count=Count('id')
        ).order_by('-match_count')

for result in results :
        print(result.name + " : " + str(result.match_count))
        percentage_score = result.match_count/filter_count * 100
```

I'm looking for a result like this:

```
Item1 - 3/3 match, 100% match
Item3 - 1/3 match, 33% match
Item2 - 0/3 match, 0% match
```

Edit #1, I tried brute forcing it a little then calculating separately.
It works but it does not look good.

```
    templist = MyModel.objects.filter(q1).annotate(match_count=Count('id'))
    accumulator = accumulator + list(templist)
    
    templist = MyModel.objects.filter(q2).annotate(match_count=Count('id'))
    accumulator = accumulator + list(templist)
    
    templist = MyModel.objects.filter(q3).annotate(match_count=Count('id'))
    accumulator = accumulator + list(templist)

    calculated_list = {}

    for item in accumulator:
        if item.name in calculated_list:
            calculated_list[item.name] += item.match_count
        else:
            calculated_list[item.name] = item.match_count

    print(calculated_list)
```

I would greatly appreciate some advice/pointers.
Is there a better or more efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `values` with `annotate`. So your query should look like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # Other Fields

filter_count = 3
q1 = Q(fieldA__iexact='AAA')
q2 = Q(fieldB__iexact='BBB')
q3 = Q(fieldC__contains='CCC')
qAll = q1 | q2 | q3

results = MyModel.objects.filter(qAll).values('name').annotate(
        match_count=Count('id')
        ).order_by('-match_count')
```